# Easy filter from HTML divisions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background-color css property of an item who matches the input criteria given:

MY HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plantilla.css">
<script src="plantilla.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Plantilla</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input" class="input" value="" />
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div id="header">Main</div>
        <div id="global1" class="global">
            Global1
            <div id="small11" class="small">aaaaaa</div>
            <div id="small12" class="small">aaabaa</div>
            <div id="small13" class="small">aaacaa</div>
            <div id="small14" class="small">aaadaa</div>
            <div id="small15" class="small">aaaeaa</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global2" class="global">
            Global2
            <div id="small21" class="small">abcdef</div>
            <div id="small22" class="small">fedcba</div>
            <div id="small23" class="small">facbde</div>
            <div id="small24" class="small">decfab</div>
            <div id="small25" class="small">bacfed</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global3" class="global">
            Global3
            <div id="small31" class="small">eeeeee</div>
            <div id="small32" class="small">eabdc</div>
            <div id="small33" class="small">bcdae</div>
            <div id="small34" class="small">dcbea</div>
            <div id="small35" class="small">eadcb</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global4" class="global">
            Global4
            <div id="small41" class="small">decab</div>
            <div id="small42" class="small">baced</div>
            <div id="small43" class="small">becad</div>
            <div id="small44" class="small">daceb</div>
            <div id="small45" class="small">cedab</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global5" class="global">
            Global5
            <div id="small51" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small52" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small53" class="small">cedab</div>
            <div id="small54" class="small">eadcb</div>
            <div id="small55" class="small">aebdc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So if in the input the "user" enters: "aebdc" it should change #small55 background-color to yellow.
If in the input there is only an: "a" it should change the background-color of all of the divs.
Obviously if none matches the criteria, none will be changed.

Comment: ok, but what is your question ? have you tried to write anything to do that ? if yes pls show your try and we'll figure out what's wrong

Comment: Looks like you need [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). I assume when you say enter _a_, all divs change, you means all divs except _small31 => eeeeee_ because it doesn't have an _a_ in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter based on the text content of the DIV

```
$('#input').on('input', function() {

    var value = this.value;

    $('.global div').css('background', '').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf(value) !== -1;
    }).css('background', 'red');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/r1eu0p3h/1/)

If you need case-insensitive search, add `toLowerCase` to both value and text.

Comment: I can see that it works exactly how i meant on the fiddle, but for some reason I can't make it work on my web, dunno why. And I was close to this answer. Going to try to make myself understand wth is wrong with me, thanks for the time anyways!.

EDIT: by the way, I don't need "toLowerCase"

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
$('#input').on('input', function() {    
  var input = $('#input').val();

  if(input.length == 6) {
    $( ".global div:contains(" + input + ")" ).css( "background", "#" + input );
  }

});
```

Comment: I didn't really meant to change the .global just the one that matches the criteria, and to yellow. I must be doing something wrong, but at least i checked my code wasn't so bad, because all of you are attempting what i was doing. Thanks, man!

Comment: I've updated it a little bit, so it less 'laggy' @Roucher

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), then set the background to the text value of the div using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```js
$('#input').on('input', function() {
  var value = this.value;

  // reset
  $('div.global div').css( "background-color", "inherit");
  
  // set new bgs
  $('div.global div:contains(' + value + ')').css( "background-color", function() {
    return '#' + $(this).text();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" class="input" value="" />
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div id="header">Main</div>
        <div id="global1" class="global">
            Global1
            <div id="small11" class="small">aaaaaa</div>
            <div id="small12" class="small">aaabaa</div>
            <div id="small13" class="small">aaacaa</div>
            <div id="small14" class="small">aaadaa</div>
            <div id="small15" class="small">aaaeaa</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global2" class="global">
            Global2
            <div id="small21" class="small">abcdef</div>
            <div id="small22" class="small">fedcba</div>
            <div id="small23" class="small">facbde</div>
            <div id="small24" class="small">decfab</div>
            <div id="small25" class="small">bacfed</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global3" class="global">
            Global3
            <div id="small31" class="small">eeeeee</div>
            <div id="small32" class="small">eabdc</div>
            <div id="small33" class="small">bcdae</div>
            <div id="small34" class="small">dcbea</div>
            <div id="small35" class="small">eadcb</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global4" class="global">
            Global4
            <div id="small41" class="small">decab</div>
            <div id="small42" class="small">baced</div>
            <div id="small43" class="small">becad</div>
            <div id="small44" class="small">daceb</div>
            <div id="small45" class="small">cedab</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global5" class="global">
            Global5
            <div id="small51" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small52" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small53" class="small">cedab</div>
            <div id="small54" class="small">eadcb</div>
            <div id="small55" class="small">aebdc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```js
//bind input change event handler
jQuery("#input").on('change',function(){
 //input that user entered
 var input = jQuery(this).val();
 //for every .small class element do the following
 jQuery('.small').each(function(){
   //this is the text written in each div
   var text = jQuery(this).text().trim();
   //if user input is substring of text
   //then give it custom class
   //othervise remove that class
   if( input == text.substring(0,input.length) ){
     jQuery(this).addClass("match");
   }else{
     jQuery(this).removeClass('match')
   }
 })
})
```

```css
.match{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plantilla.css">
<script src="plantilla.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Plantilla</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input" class="input" value="" />
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div id="header">Main</div>
        <div id="global1" class="global">
            Global1
            <div id="small11" class="small">aaaaaa</div>
            <div id="small12" class="small">aaabaa</div>
            <div id="small13" class="small">aaacaa</div>
            <div id="small14" class="small">aaadaa</div>
            <div id="small15" class="small">aaaeaa</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global2" class="global">
            Global2
            <div id="small21" class="small">abcdef</div>
            <div id="small22" class="small">fedcba</div>
            <div id="small23" class="small">facbde</div>
            <div id="small24" class="small">decfab</div>
            <div id="small25" class="small">bacfed</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global3" class="global">
            Global3
            <div id="small31" class="small">eeeeee</div>
            <div id="small32" class="small">eabdc</div>
            <div id="small33" class="small">bcdae</div>
            <div id="small34" class="small">dcbea</div>
            <div id="small35" class="small">eadcb</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global4" class="global">
            Global4
            <div id="small41" class="small">decab</div>
            <div id="small42" class="small">baced</div>
            <div id="small43" class="small">becad</div>
            <div id="small44" class="small">daceb</div>
            <div id="small45" class="small">cedab</div>
        </div>
        <div id="global5" class="global">
            Global5
            <div id="small51" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small52" class="small">cadeb</div>
            <div id="small53" class="small">cedab</div>
            <div id="small54" class="small">eadcb</div>
            <div id="small55" class="small">aebdc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```